# in Hibernate a user x is doing n number of opertation of update from so many machine at a time of user x in hiebernate how we handle it

Tags: java, hibernate

A User x login successfully and doing update 
user x is login  from so many system 
like user x login from 20 systems these 20 system is going to update in hibernate at a time how we handle it

Whether it is possible ? if Possible then how we will do

Answer (score 0):

20 different system will create 20 different session in hibernate, No matter the user is same or different, what matters is the table which is getting updated.
And if multiple user are updating the table hibernate will manage the data it self, since SessionFactory is thread safe.

when system2 will update then it will first save the changes of system1 , and then it will update system2 changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate/JPA can manage concurrency without an issue.

Multiple sessions writing to your database simultaneously will first invoke your database's support for atomic operations.  This means that row level locks will first be invoked and based on activity, escalated perhaps to datapage locks and finally to table level locks as needed.  This is how relational database systems work out of the box.

The concern here is how your business process fetches data, alters the state, and then persists changes back to the database.

### Naive Way

The naive way is to simply fetch your database row, alter it's state and persist it back to your database like this:

```
Entity entity = entityManager.find(Entity.class, entityId);
entity.setAttribute(someAlteredValue); // unit of work
entityManager.merge(entity);
```

The problem with this approach is that if multiple transactions modify the same database row, the end state will end up being whatever was merged last.  In cases where the same database rows are being managed by multiple sessions, this is certainly not ideal and guards should be put in place.

### Database - Read/update locks

There are use cases where it is acceptable to apply update locks on rows at read time because we know the unit of work will be short lived.

```
Entity entity = entityManager.find(Entity.class, entityId, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE); // update lock at read
entity.setAttribute(someAlteredValue); // unit of work
entityManager.merge(entity);
```

This works and maintains concurrency across multiple transactions, but doesn't come without some incurred cost.

As more row-level locks are applied to a table, the database may escalate the locks to the table level, and table level locks essentially create severe bottlenecks in concurrent operations.

### Optimistic Locking

This is the most preferred way to manage locking in a highly concurrent environment.  You add an additional field, annotated with `@Version` and as operations occur against your entity, hibernate will manage this field for you by tracking a version number of your row.

```
 try {
   Entity entity = entityManager.find(Entity.class, entityId);
   entity.setAttribute(someAlteredValue); // unit of work
   entityManager.merge(entity);
 }
 catch(OptimisticLockException ex) { 
   // some other transaction has changed the entity.
 }
```

In the above code, had no other operation changed the entity between the time it was fetched and changed, no exception is thrown and the transaction commits as desired.

Had any other transaction made changes between the time this code had fetched and merged the changes, an `OptimisticLockException` would be thrown, allowing the application to decide how to best handle the situation.

For example, you may want to inform the user that the record has been modified and that they need to requery the form to get the latest data, make their changes, and save it again.